# Emacs minibuffer message when typing C-x

Tags: emacs, elisp

Well. When I type some first keys of the key series, emacs write those keys in minibuffer after some interval of time. Like that: Typing `C-x 4` will make `C-x 4-` visible in minibuffer.

The question is: can this be modified? I was thinking about making something like combining part of key-help (generated by `C-h` when type some keys) with this string.
Can interval for waiting this message be shorten too?
Is it subroutine?

*Edited, new question*

There is a message when I quit emacs with `C-x C-c` and have modified buffers, that ask me if I want to save them. **How can I know that this message is here?** I tried to look in `(minibuffer-prompt) (minibuffer-contents) (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max))`, selecting `(select-window (minibuffer-window))`. Nothing gives me results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the timing of this help message by setting [`suggest-key-bindings`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/M_002dx.html) to a larger/smaller number.

```
(setq suggest-key-bindings 5) ; wait 5 seconds
```

There is no easy way to customize the behavior, you'd have to edit the C code for `execute-extended-command`, or use a replacement for it which also provides the help.  One possibility for a replacement is the [`anything-complete`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/anything-complete.el) library which has a replacement for `execute-extended-command` (note: I haven't tried it).  It builds on top of the package [`anything`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything), which is a different experience than the standard Emacs.

Comment: `suggest-key-bindings` is not exactly what I asking. Example: we have some function on `C-c C-k`, and we type just `C-c`. After short time, we see `C-c-` in the minibuffer. It's not _suggestion_, which is telling after `M-x forward-char` that it is bound to `C-f`. It would be nice to know, which function makes the text I want. I'll try to play with fset, saving subr in different symbol.

Comment: @desudesudesu Gotcha, I misread.  Unfortunately, the command loop for reading in the input events is even less accessible than `suggest-key-bindings`, so the answer is that it's not really possible to do what you want w/out modifying the C code.

Comment: That's a pity. However, [I wrote desired functions even without it, using timers](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?utmy0t4uzj0w). How can I see that somebody uses minibuffer in `keylist-function`? You can see things commented out, they don't work(exept last two lines, they work).

Comment: FWIW, wrt `execute-extended-command` and suggesting key bindings (which I do understand is not really what you were after), see the code for [`icicle-execute-extended-command-1`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-cmd1.el).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the user option `echo-keystrokes` controls how much time elapses before the prefix key is shown in the minibuffer.  From (emacs) `Echo Area Customization`:

```
User Option: echo-keystrokes
     This variable determines how much time should elapse before command
     characters echo.  Its value must be an integer or floating point
     number, which specifies the number of seconds to wait before
     echoing.  If the user types a prefix key (such as `C-x') and then
     delays this many seconds before continuing, the prefix key is
     echoed in the echo area.  (Once echoing begins in a key sequence,
     all subsequent characters in the same key sequence are echoed
     immediately.)

     If the value is zero, then command input is not echoed.
```

Comment: Well, I found myself this too. It can't be used to determine the echo, but it's good thing to be customized to smaller value anyway. Voting you up.

Comment: Drew as in Drew Adams? Thanks man, this answer worked for me, voting up.

Answer (score 0):

[I wrote working version of what I wanted to implement.](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?utmy0t4uzj0w)

To use, `(require 'keylist)`, copy one or two last lines to .emacs and uncomment them.

As you can see through this code, I used this

```
(not cursor-in-echo-area)
(not (minibufferp))
(not (= 13 (aref (this-command-keys-vector) 0)))
```

to find out, if my minibuffer, or echo area is in use. 
The difference between them is that minibuffer is used to read, and echo area is used to message something.
When you type `C-x C-c` cursor is placed in echo area, and value of `cursor-in-echo-area` is changed.

The last string `(= 13 (aref (this-command-keys-vector) 0))` is the most funny. It is used to catch things like `query-replace`. When making raplacements, `(this-command-keys-vector)` shows that `RET` is the first key pressed, then keys of your choise(y,n). As far as I don't have key-sequences starting with `RET`, i am okay with this.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but when I run it, it doesn't do anything, except hide all minibuffer updates when I press a multiple-keystroke command.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman Updated my [everfall paste](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?utmy0t4uzj0w) to last edited version. Ive dropped to use it since it works slow, making my cpu jump to 30-50% when executing. I'm starting it only when I launch new mode. Make sure you call `M-x keylist` with any argument. Without one, it is turned down. So, `C-u M-x keylist`